# Well definedness of the p fractional Laplace operator

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Let $s\in(0,1)$, $p>1$ and $N\geq 1$. We define the fractional p Laplace operator $(-\Delta)_p^{s}$ by
$$
(-\Delta)_p^{s}u(x):=\lim_{r\to 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_r(x)}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^{p-2}(u(x)-u(y))}{|x-y|^{n+ps}}\,dy.
$$
Can somebody please help me under what condition on the function $u$ the above operator is well defined?

Thanking you.

Comment: Yes. Holder will give the following:

Comment: $$(-\Delta)_p^{s}u\leq\lim_{r\to 0}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_r(x)}|u(x)-u(y)||x-y|^{-N-ps}\,dy)^\frac{p-1}{p}(\int_{\mathbb{R}^N\setminus B_r(x)}{|x-y|^{-N-ps}}\,dy)^\frac{1}{p}.$$ But why the RHS is finite?

Comment: Do you think the following condition on $u$ i.e. $$u\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^N)$$ such that $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^N}(|u(x)|^{p-1}(1+|x|)^{-N-sp}\,dx)<\infty$$ will be enough for the well definedness?